# How to repeat watermark in excel created

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

In my webform project, I generate excel file with `Aspose` in C#, and I add watermark to it with this code:

```
 Aspose.Cells.Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoPresetTextEffect effect = Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoPresetTextEffect.TextEffect2;
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.Shape wordart = sheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(effect,"WATERMARKTEXT", "Arial Black", 47, false, false, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50, 300);
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoFillFormat wordArtFormat = wordart.FillFormat;
            wordArtFormat.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            wordArtFormat.Transparency = 0.8;
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoLineFormat lineFormat = wordart.LineFormat;
            lineFormat.IsVisible = false;
            return workbook;
```

But I want to repeat this watermark horizontally and vertically in each sheet. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this method for setting background instead of watermark :

```
  private static Aspose.Cells.Workbook AddExcelWaterMark(Aspose.Cells.Workbook workbook)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/ExcelBackGround.png");
            byte[] bgBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            foreach (Aspose.Cells.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Worksheets)
                sheet.SetBackground(bgBuffer);

            return workbook;
        }
        catch
        {
            return workbook;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the following sample code using Aspose.Cells APIs to accomplish your task for your reference:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\Book1.xlsx");
            //Add watermark to the first worksheet.
            Aspose.Cells.Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoPresetTextEffect effect = Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoPresetTextEffect.TextEffect2;
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.Shape wordart = sheet.Shapes.AddTextEffect(effect, "WATERMARKTEXT", "Arial Black", 47, false, false, 1, 1, 1, 1, 50, 300);
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoFillFormat wordArtFormat = wordart.FillFormat;
            wordArtFormat.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            wordArtFormat.Transparency = 0.8;
            Aspose.Cells.Drawing.MsoLineFormat lineFormat = wordart.LineFormat;
            lineFormat.IsVisible = false;


            //Now add watermark to the second worksheet as it is.
            Aspose.Cells.Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[1];
            worksheet1.Shapes.AddCopy(wordart, wordart.UpperLeftRow, wordart.Top, wordart.UpperLeftColumn, wordart.Left);


            //Now add watermark to the third worksheet vertically.
            Aspose.Cells.Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Worksheets[2];
            worksheet2.Shapes.AddCopy(wordart, wordart.UpperLeftRow, wordart.Top, wordart.UpperLeftColumn, wordart.Left);
            worksheet2.Shapes[0].RotationAngle = 90;

            workbook.Save("e:\\test2\\out.xlsx");
```

Note: I am working as Support developer/Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: I want to repeat a watermark to one sheet, I couldn't do it with watermark then set background for sheet and the result was what I want.

Comment: Yes, setting background image (you can create a picture with your desired watermark text and save to image format (e.g, PNG)) can suit your needs as  you need to place watermark/text multiple time in a single worksheet.